# aligning images in React JS side by side using CSS map method

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

To align images side by side that are written using map method in React JS and CSS
To align images side by side that are written using map method in React JS and CSS
To align images side by side that are written using map method in React JS and CSS

before:

[image]

```
import React from 'react'
import HomeFooterImages from "./HomeFooterImages";

const HomeFooterDetails = () => { //landing page footer images not wokring
  return (
        <div className="home5Main">
            {
              HomeFooterImages.map((curElem) =>
              {
                  return (
                      <div className="home5Main1">
                            <img className="home5Main1Img" src={curElem.img} />
                      </div>
                      
                  )
              })
            }
          </div>
  )
}


export default HomeFooterDetails;
```

Answer (score 0):

For following results

[image]

Add following CSS:

```css
.home5Main {
  margin-top: 5%;
  border: 2px solid grey;
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
}

.home5Main1Img {
  float: left;
  width: 13%;
  height: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You Should use FlexBox for this scenario. Bydefault direction of flex will be row-wise.

```
.home5Main1 {
    padding:"5px";

}
.home5Main1Img{
  width: "200px";
  height: "400px";
}

.home5Main {
  display:"flex";
  width:"100%"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Code Solution:https://codesandbox.io/s/sharp-kare-np3e0?file=/src/App.js**

```
import "./styles.css";
import { ImagesElement } from "./HomeFooterImages";
export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="home5Main">
      {ImagesElement.map((curElem) => {
        return <img className="home5Main1Img" src={curElem.img} />;
      })}
    </div>
  );
}


.home5Main {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}
```

**explanation:** You are returning home5Main1 div for HomeFooterImages map function since you rendering div(which is block element) images will come one below the other.
In my code, I am only returning images from map function which works and used flex just add little spice to it